# send printed result into my database as a string

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-graph-api

I want to store my result as just location name, i found the result as an array but it can't stored in my database, it print only a name 'array' in my database

```
try {
            $user6 = $fb->get('/me?fields=location');
            $user6 = $user6->getGraphNode()->asArray();

            //echo $user6->location->name;
            $user6->location->name; 
            echo "<pre/>";print_r($user6);


        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            session_destroy();
            // if access token is invalid or expired you can simply redirect to login page using header() function
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
```

For save my result in my databse, my code is below:

```
$location= $user6 ['location'];

echo $location;

mysql_query("insert into newmember(location) values('$location')") or die(mysql_error());
```

my result is :

```
Array
(
    [location] => Array
        (
            [id] => 101889586519301
            [name] => Dhaka, Bangladesh
        )

    [id] => 1589273127757008
)
```

Comment: What is the value of `$location`?

Comment: my result is below actually i want to save it only location "Bangladesh".              Array
(
    [location] => Array
        (
            [id] => 101889586519301
            [name] => Dhaka, Bangladesh
        )

    [id] => 1589273127757008
)

Comment: Try $location= $user6 ['location']['name'];

Comment: yes it works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to store just the location name in the database, you can do:

```
$location = $user6['location']['name'];
```

If you want to store the array itself, you can either `json_encode` the data or `serialize` it (note that you will need to do the reverse if you later want to use the data):

```
// encode
$location = json_encode( $user6['location'] );

// decode
$location = json_decode( $user6['location'] );
```

or

```
// encode
$location = serialize( $user6['location'] );

// decode
$location = unserialize( $user6['location'] );
```

Comment: i use php code. any way thanks for your feed back. result is find when i use your first line code.